# Test Spring Data Repository to fail upon submission of invalid (Validation violation) Entity

Tags: spring, bean-validation, spring-test

I am trying to test Spring Data Repository, particularly to test that exception would be thrown upon passing Entity with the wrong parameters. Entity is annotated with Java Bean Validation annotations `@NotNull` and `@Email`

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = PatientPKServiceApplication.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class PatientPKRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
private PatientPKRepository repository;


@Rule
public ExpectedException thrownException = ExpectedException.none();


 @Test
public void newEntityWithInvalidParametersShouldThrownConstraintViolations() throws Exception {
    this.thrownException.expect(ConstraintViolationException.class);
    this.repository.save(new PatientPK(null, null, null));
}
```

Repository is

```
public interface PatientPkRepository extends JpaRepository<PatientPk, Long> {
}
```

Test fails,

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected test to throw an instance of javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException

    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.failDueToMissingException(ExpectedException.java:263)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException.access$200(ExpectedException.java:106)
```

what is the best way to test this behavior? I don't want to validate manually.

---

Update SOLUTION : As suggested by JB Nizet (see answer below) we need to ensure that Persistence Context is actually flushed. Changing `repository.save` to `repository.saveAndFlush()` worked out.

Comment: 1. Can you show your repository class 2. when you say test fails what is the message / exception you are getting?

Comment: @pvpkiran Thanks, updated.

Comment: FYI: this is documented in the Testing chapter of the Spring Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx-false-positives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test) says:

> By default, data JPA tests are transactional and roll back at the end of each test.

So since your test is transactional, and since it rollbacks, and since you never flush anywhere, the save() operation never actually tries to write to the database, and the validation constraints, executed before flush, are never validated.

Comment: **at the end of each test.**

Comment: Exactly, but exception should be thrown before method exits.

Comment: It can only be thrown if a flush happens during the test. But there is none.

Comment: So you mean that validation happens only upon flushing?

Comment: Thanks, I changed to `saveAndFlash()` and it works now. You may want to update your answer to reflect solution.